# How can i show UIAlertView while moving to background of screen or killing App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

Iam trying to display an alert like  `"Some process are currently doing .Please dont close your app now."`   While user try minimise or kill the app from device. Is that possible to display `UIAlertview` like that ??

Please help me

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Impossible..

we get Home button Press Event at this two Delegate Method If the application is sent to background, `applicationDidEnterBackground` Called.

And while app interrupted by sms, call , video call then `applicationWillResignActive` called but we are not stop to application going to `applicationWillResignActive` or `applicationWillResignActive`

we just display UIAlertview while this Both method called but we can't stop to perform this Method.

Answer (score 1):

No, because you won't know that the app will be minimized at all or too late to display a message. Be prepared to always be suspended, and handle that event gracefully, regardless of what you're doing.

Comment: At this situation ,if we are calling some server for data and user try to minimise and kill the app ,after  he open the app and its crashing   .why???

Comment: So i thought  in between some process we have to display some messages  like "process are running in your app"

Comment: @Navi you need to check if `data` download then call your method, if not, download again.

Comment: @Navi: You can schedule a background task to continue the download from the server in the background. Without any code I have no idea why your app crashes when it's opened back up. Oh, and no need to present an alert to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this by `NSLocalNotification`.

There are many posts here to get the local notification setup. Just go through it and you'll ultimately get the idea.